# Simple form - checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I have the models Search, Color and ColorsSearch:

```
def Search
   has_many :colors, :through => :colors_searches
end

def Color
   has_many :searches, :through => :colors_searhes
end

def ColorsSearch
   belongs_to :color
   belongs_to :search
end
```

In my view I want to have multiple color checboxes and when a user submit the form, a new search record is created with the colors_serches records (one for each colors selected).

```
 <% Color.with_products.order(:name).each do |color| %>
     <% if color.name != 'none' %>
         <div class="checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" name="search[color_id]" value="<%= color.id %>" id="color-checkbox-<%= color.id %>">
             <label for="color-checkbox-<%= color.id %>" style="background-color: <%= color.hex %>;"></label>
         </div>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

## Two questions:

1. How can I rewrite the code above in my view to achieve this using simple form ?
2. How should the controller look like?

Thank you for your ideas,
Miroslav

## UPDATE

The following code should do most of the solution I am looking for, the only piece that is remaining is:

- hide labels (label: false, does not seem to be working as expected)
- set background-color dynamically for each of the generated labels based on the Color field. The model Color has an attribute :hex, which stores hex identification of the color, for instance: #FFFFFF for white color etc.

  ```
  <%= s.association :colors, collection: Color.with_products.order(:name), label: false, as: :check_boxes %>
  ```

I would need something similar to this code, so for each of the colors I would set different background-color:

```
 <%= s.association :colors, collection: Color.with_products.order(:name), label: false, as: :check_boxes, :label_html => { :style => "background-color: #{:hex};" } %>
```

## SOLUTION

So I found two solutions (probably not so elegant, but they work):

1. I was able to find out how to append style for every input and if you can render specific colors for inputs, you can then easily apply jQuery to copy that style for tables.

My View:

```
<%= s.association :colors, collection: Color.collection_for_filter, label: false, as: :check_boxes %>
```

Color Model:

```
def self.collection_for_filter
     array = []
     Color.with_products.each { |c| array << ["#{c.id}", "#{c.id}", { :style => "background-color: #{c.hex}" }] }
     array
end
```

2. I iterate all the colors and for each of the color I render an input and label with custom values I need.

" name="search[color_ids][]" id="search_color_ids_">
" for="search_color_ids_">

```
<% Color.with_products.each do |color| %>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="<%= color.id %>" name="search[color_ids][]" id="search_color_ids_<%= color.id %>">
    <label class="collection_check_boxes" style="background-color: <%= color.hex %>" for="search_color_ids_<%= color.id %>">
    </label>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I chose the option 2 as it seems to better solution with no need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do most of the solution I am looking for, the only piece that is remaining is:

- hide labels (label: false, does not seem to be working as expected)
- set background-color dynamically for each of the generated labels based on the Color field. The model Color has an attribute :hex, which stores hex identification of the color, for instance: #FFFFFF for white color etc.

See UPDATE for the code reference.